# Downloading GeoExplorer and installing outside suite?

Tags: qgis, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I already have QGIS, GeoServer and QGIS all configured, but I would love to add GeoExplorer so I can publish maps easily.

Is there a way to do this without having to install the whole opengeo suite?

Is it possible to install GeoExplorer on its own to work with QGIS?

Are there other options for publishing as a web application with edit functionality?

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this question? I also have geoserver, postgreSQL/PostGIS, Apache, and QGIS. Is it possible to install GeoExplorer separately?  Thanks

Comment: Actually when I ran the installer it allowed me to select the components that I wanted.

Comment: Which installer? OSGeo4W Setup?